# How to calculate fractal dimension by fitting on a log-log plot?

Tags: computational-physics, dimensional-analysis, complex-systems, fractals

I have simulated a **DLA pattern** by MC method and the data is for fractal dimension. The **right column** is the **number of particle N(r)** into radius r and the **left column** is the **radius r**. I plotted a log-log plot by **Origin** software. But I have a problem with fitting onto the plot. I do not know which part of the data should be considered and others should be deleted to fit on the log-log plot accurately and show me a correct fractal dimension. Please guide me to do it. In fact, I should consider a **scaling region** for calculating the slope (fractal dimension) but I do not know how I do it.

The result is below:

[image: Graph]

Two circles show two regions which should be considered accurately.

My data is shown below:

```
      r N(r)
      0 1
      1 8
      2 17
      3 24
      4 35
      5 47
      6 61
      7 75
      8 95
      9 116
      10    136
      11    156
      12    175
      13    204
      14    236
      15    265
      16    289
      17    312
      18    343
      19    369
      20    392
      21    418
      22    450
      23    479
      24    502
      25    536
      26    575
      27    609
      28    646
      29    684
      30    721
      31    757
      32    794
      33    837
      34    883
      35    923
      36    978
      37    1018
      38    1054
      39    1107
      40    1151
      41    1204
      42    1247
      43    1303
      44    1360
      45    1416
      46    1476
      47    1523
      48    1573
      49    1621
      50    1666
      51    1715
      52    1749
      53    1785
      54    1831
      55    1896
      56    1950
      57    2019
      58    2071
      59    2130
      60    2177
      61    2236
      62    2304
      63    2349
      64    2403
      65    2477
      66    2542
      67    2610
      68    2680
      69    2738
      70    2811
      71    2882
      72    2946
      73    3027
      74    3111
      75    3198
      76    3288
      77    3384
      78    3474
      79    3573
      80    3660
      81    3732
      82    3818
      83    3886
      84    3979
      85    4061
      86    4129
      87    4211
      88    4284
      89    4385
      90    4470
      91    4538
      92    4614
      93    4689
      94    4762
      95    4832
      96    4921
      97    5007
      98    5097
      99    5193
      100   5284
      101   5369
      102   5470
      103   5565
      104   5660
      105   5755
      106   5853
      107   5959
      108   6052
      109   6159
      110   6263
      111   6376
      112   6503
      113   6611
      114   6719
      115   6809
      116   6893
      117   7001
      118   7112
      119   7225
      120   7335
      121   7434
      122   7580
      123   7734
      124   7868
      125   7991
      126   8117
      127   8245
      128   8383
      129   8520
      130   8670
      131   8785
      132   8914
      133   9041
      134   9171
      135   9297
      136   9429
      137   9557
      138   9675
      139   9803
      140   9929
      141   10037
      142   10143
      143   10274
      144   10429
      145   10549
      146   10659
      147   10766
      148   10873
      149   10978
      150   11086
      151   11196
      152   11315
      153   11445
      154   11559
      155   11681
      156   11815
      157   11947
      158   12081
      159   12218
      160   12370
      161   12536
      162   12669
      163   12812
      164   12941
      165   13061
      166   13176
      167   13307
      168   13433
      169   13566
      170   13689
      171   13812
      172   13935
      173   14052
      174   14167
      175   14256
      176   14348
      177   14453
      178   14561
      179   14676
      180   14768
      181   14840
      182   14915
      183   14995
      184   15065
      185   15139
      186   15195
      187   15253
      188   15325
      189   15404
      190   15489
      191   15570
      192   15649
      193   15745
      194   15835
      195   15940
      196   16038
      197   16146
      198   16248
      199   16356
      200   16483
      201   16570
      202   16650
      203   16747
      204   16847
      205   16955
      206   17046
      207   17152
      208   17252
      209   17353
      210   17441
      211   17542
      212   17627
      213   17725
      214   17804
      215   17893
      216   17983
      217   18079
      218   18161
      219   18240
      220   18343
      221   18440
      222   18546
      223   18644
      224   18729
      225   18821
      226   18921
      227   19008
      228   19090
      229   19179
      230   19260
      231   19328
      232   19404
      233   19491
      234   19575
      235   19647
      236   19728
      237   19786
      238   19861
      239   19939
      240   20016
      241   20089
      242   20161
      243   20233
      244   20295
      245   20378
      246   20450
      247   20515
      248   20619
      249   20692
      250   20780
      251   20846
      252   20925
      253   20982
      254   21041
      255   21102
      256   21151
      257   21206
      258   21263
      259   21334
      260   21383
      261   21434
      262   21498
      263   21570
      264   21670
      265   21769
      266   21846
      267   21907
      268   21973
      269   22047
      270   22113
      271   22178
      272   22232
      273   22278
      274   22307
      275   22339
      276   22387
      277   22432
      278   22497
      279   22555
      280   22616
      281   22680
      282   22728
      283   22775
      284   22822
      285   22856
      286   22886
      287   22925
      288   22961
      289   23004
      290   23045
      291   23093
      292   23128
      293   23185
      294   23239
      295   23283
      296   23330
      297   23373
      298   23415
      299   23452
      300   23481
      301   23528
      302   23576
      303   23627
      304   23671
      305   23705
      306   23735
      307   23771
      308   23825
      309   23871
      310   23910
      311   23954
      312   23994
      313   24033
      314   24066
      315   24093
      316   24126
      317   24156
      318   24201
      319   24227
      320   24249
      321   24277
      322   24290
      323   24309
      324   24357
      325   24402
      326   24450
      327   24483
      328   24514
      329   24536
      330   24574
      331   24605
      332   24625
      333   24655
      334   24684
      335   24701
      336   24725
      337   24747
      338   24761
      339   24784
      340   24809
      341   24830
      342   24852
      343   24870
      344   24891
      345   24906
      346   24917
      347   24931
      348   24945
      349   24959
      350   24971
      351   24982
      352   24990
      353   24993
      354   24995
      355   24999
      356   25000
      357   25001
      358   25001
      359   25001
      360   25001
      361   25001
      362   25001
      363   25001
      364   25001
      365   25001
      366   25001
      367   25001
      368   25001
      369   25001
      370   25001
      371   25001
      372   25001
      373   25001
      374   25001
      375   25001
      376   25001
      377   25001
      378   25001
      379   25001
      380   25001
      381   25001
      382   25001
      383   25001
      384   25001
      385   25001
      386   25001
      387   25001
      388   25001
      389   25001
      390   25001
      391   25001
      392   25001
      393   25001
      394   25001
      395   25001
      396   25001
      397   25001
      398   25001
      399   25001
      400   25001
      401   25001
      402   25001
      403   25001
      404   25001
      405   25001
      406   25001
      407   25001
      408   25001
      409   25001
      410   25001
      411   25001
      412   25001
      413   25001
      414   25001
      415   25001
      416   25001
      417   25001
      418   25001
      419   25001
      420   25001
      421   25001
      422   25001
      423   25001
      424   25001
      425   25001
      426   25001
      427   25001
      428   25001
      429   25001
      430   25001
      431   25001
      432   25001
      433   25001
      434   25001
      435   25001
      436   25001
      437   25001
      438   25001
      439   25001
      440   25001
      441   25001
      442   25001
      443   25001
      444   25001
      445   25001
      446   25001
      447   25001
      448   25001
      449   25001
      450   25001
      451   25001
      452   25001
      453   25001
      454   25001
      455   25001
      456   25001
      457   25001
      458   25001
      459   25001
      460   25001
      461   25001
      462   25001
      463   25001
      464   25001
      465   25001
      466   25001
      467   25001
      468   25001
      469   25001
      470   25001
      471   25001
      472   25001
      473   25001
      474   25001
      475   25001
      476   25001
      477   25001
      478   25001
      479   25001
      480   25001
      481   25001
      482   25001
      483   25001
      484   25001
      485   25001
      486   25001
      487   25001
      488   25001
      489   25001
      490   25001
      491   25001
      492   25001
      493   25001
      494   25001
      495   25001
      496   25001
      497   25001
      498   25001
      499   25001
      500   25001
      501   25001
      502   25001
      503   25001
      504   25001
      505   25001
      506   25001
      507   25001
      508   25001
      509   25001
      510   25001
      511   25001
      512   25001
      513   25001
      514   25001
      515   25001
      516   25001
      517   25001
      518   25001
      519   25001
      520   25001
      521   25001
      522   25001
      523   25001
      524   25001
      525   25001
      526   25001
      527   25001
      528   25001
      529   25001
      530   25001
      531   25001
      532   25001
      533   25001
      534   25001
      535   25001
      536   25001
      537   25001
      538   25001
      539   25001
      540   25001
      541   25001
      542   25001
      543   25001
      544   25001
      545   25001
      546   25001
      547   25001
      548   25001
      549   25001
      550   25001
      551   25001
      552   25001
      553   25001
      554   25001
      555   25001
      556   25001
      557   25001
      558   25001
      559   25001
      560   25001
      561   25001
      562   25001
      563   25001
      564   25001
      565   25001
      566   25001
      567   25001
      568   25001
      569   25001
      570   25001
      571   25001
      572   25001
      573   25001
      574   25001
      575   25001
      576   25001
      577   25001
      578   25001
      579   25001
      580   25001
      581   25001
      582   25001
      583   25001
      584   25001
      585   25001
      586   25001
      587   25001
      588   25001
      589   25001
      590   25001
      591   25001
      592   25001
      593   25001
      594   25001
      595   25001
      596   25001
      597   25001
      598   25001
      599   25001
      600   25001
      601   25001
      602   25001
      603   25001
      604   25001
      605   25001
      606   25001
      607   25001
      608   25001
      609   25001
      610   25001
      611   25001
      612   25001
      613   25001
      614   25001
      615   25001
      616   25001
      617   25001
      618   25001
      619   25001
      620   25001
      621   25001
      622   25001
      623   25001
      624   25001
      625   25001
      626   25001
      627   25001
      628   25001
      629   25001
      630   25001
      631   25001
      632   25001
      633   25001
      634   25001
      635   25001
      636   25001
      637   25001
      638   25001
      639   25001
      640   25001
      641   25001
      642   25001
      643   25001
      644   25001
      645   25001
      646   25001
      647   25001
      648   25001
      649   25001
      650   25001
      651   25001
      652   25001
      653   25001
      654   25001
      655   25001
      656   25001
      657   25001
      658   25001
      659   25001
      660   25001
      661   25001
      662   25001
      663   25001
      664   25001
      665   25001
      666   25001
      667   25001
      668   25001
      669   25001
      670   25001
      671   25001
      672   25001
      673   25001
      674   25001
      675   25001
      676   25001
      677   25001
      678   25001
      679   25001
      680   25001
      681   25001
      682   25001
      683   25001
      684   25001
      685   25001
      686   25001
      687   25001
      688   25001
      689   25001
      690   25001
      691   25001
      692   25001
      693   25001
      694   25001
      695   25001
      696   25001
      697   25001
      698   25001
      699   25001
      700   25001
      701   25001
      702   25001
      703   25001
      704   25001
      705   25001
      706   25001
      707   25001
      708   25001
      709   25001
      710   25001
      711   25001
      712   25001
      713   25001
      714   25001
      715   25001
      716   25001
      717   25001
      718   25001
      719   25001
      720   25001
      721   25001
      722   25001
      723   25001
      724   25001
      725   25001
      726   25001
      727   25001
      728   25001
      729   25001
      730   25001
      731   25001
      732   25001
      733   25001
      734   25001
      735   25001
      736   25001
      737   25001
      738   25001
      739   25001
      740   25001
      741   25001
      742   25001
      743   25001
      744   25001
      745   25001
      746   25001
      747   25001
      748   25001
      749   25001
      750   25001
      751   25001
      752   25001
      753   25001
      754   25001
      755   25001
      756   25001
      757   25001
      758   25001
      759   25001
      760   25001
      761   25001
      762   25001
      763   25001
      764   25001
      765   25001
      766   25001
      767   25001
      768   25001
      769   25001
      770   25001
      771   25001
      772   25001
      773   25001
      774   25001
      775   25001
      776   25001
      777   25001
      778   25001
      779   25001
      780   25001
      781   25001
      782   25001
      783   25001
      784   25001
      785   25001
      786   25001
      787   25001
      788   25001
      789   25001
      790   25001
      791   25001
      792   25001
      793   25001
      794   25001
      795   25001
      796   25001
      797   25001
      798   25001
      799   25001
      800   25001
      801   25001
      802   25001
      803   25001
      804   25001
      805   25001
      806   25001
      807   25001
      808   25001
      809   25001
      810   25001
      811   25001
      812   25001
      813   25001
      814   25001
      815   25001
      816   25001
      817   25001
      818   25001
      819   25001
      820   25001
      821   25001
      822   25001
      823   25001
      824   25001
      825   25001
      826   25001
      827   25001
      828   25001
      829   25001
      830   25001
      831   25001
      832   25001
      833   25001
      834   25001
      835   25001
      836   25001
      837   25001
      838   25001
      839   25001
      840   25001
      841   25001
      842   25001
      843   25001
      844   25001
      845   25001
      846   25001
      847   25001
      848   25001
      849   25001
      850   25001
      851   25001
      852   25001
      853   25001
      854   25001
      855   25001
      856   25001
      857   25001
      858   25001
      859   25001
      860   25001
      861   25001
      862   25001
      863   25001
      864   25001
      865   25001
      866   25001
      867   25001
      868   25001
      869   25001
      870   25001
      871   25001
      872   25001
      873   25001
      874   25001
      875   25001
      876   25001
      877   25001
      878   25001
      879   25001
      880   25001
      881   25001
      882   25001
      883   25001
      884   25001
      885   25001
      886   25001
      887   25001
      888   25001
      889   25001
      890   25001
      891   25001
      892   25001
      893   25001
      894   25001
      895   25001
      896   25001
      897   25001
      898   25001
      899   25001
      900   25001
      901   25001
      902   25001
      903   25001
      904   25001
      905   25001
      906   25001
      907   25001
      908   25001
      909   25001
      910   25001
      911   25001
      912   25001
      913   25001
      914   25001
      915   25001
      916   25001
      917   25001
      918   25001
      919   25001
      920   25001
      921   25001
      922   25001
      923   25001
      924   25001
      925   25001
      926   25001
      927   25001
      928   25001
      929   25001
      930   25001
      931   25001
      932   25001
      933   25001
      934   25001
      935   25001
      936   25001
      937   25001
      938   25001
      939   25001
      940   25001
      941   25001
      942   25001
      943   25001
      944   25001
      945   25001
      946   25001
      947   25001
      948   25001
      949   25001
      950   25001
      951   25001
      952   25001
      953   25001
      954   25001
      955   25001
      956   25001
      957   25001
      958   25001
      959   25001
      960   25001
      961   25001
      962   25001
      963   25001
      964   25001
      965   25001
      966   25001
      967   25001
      968   25001
      969   25001
      970   25001
      971   25001
      972   25001
      973   25001
      974   25001
      975   25001
      976   25001
      977   25001
      978   25001
      979   25001
      980   25001
      981   25001
      982   25001
      983   25001
      984   25001
      985   25001
      986   25001
      987   25001
      988   25001
      989   25001
      990   25001
      991   25001
      992   25001
      993   25001
      994   25001
      995   25001
      996   25001
      997   25001
      998   25001
      999   25001
      1000  25001
      1001  25001
      1002  25001
      1003  25001
      1004  25001
      1005  25001
      1006  25001
      1007  25001
      1008  25001
      1009  25001
      1010  25001
      1011  25001
      1012  25001
      1013  25001
      1014  25001
      1015  25001
      1016  25001
      1017  25001
      1018  25001
      1019  25001
      1020  25001
      1021  25001
      1022  25001
      1023  25001
```

Comment: What does the data denote? There are different ways of calculating fractal dimensions (box counting seems likely here). Also, how do you know if you have the "correct" fractal dimension? Please refine your question and show what you are trying to do.

Comment: It is often (though not absolutely always) the case that the fitting problem is formally independent of the physics. That is, getting fit parameters out of a log-log plot is a problem that comes up over and over again and the way you do it has nothing to do with the fact that the data arose int he context of trying to learn something about fractal dimension.

Comment: @AndersSandberg Thank you for your response. Actually, I have simulated a DLA pattern by MC method and the data is for fractal dimension. The left column is the number of particle N(r) into radius r and the right column is the radius r. I plotted a log-log plot by Origin software. But I have a problem with fitting onto the plot. In fact, I should consider a scaling region for calculating the slope (fractal dimension) but I do not know how I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you plotted onto the fit is the one you are interested in.

Note that you are computing a quantity different from the box-dimension, which is the quantity generally used for these estimates.

The box dimension is defined as:

$$
d_B=lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{log\;N(\epsilon)}{log\;(\frac{1}{\epsilon})}
$$
While you are using the quantity: $d=\frac{log\;N(R)}{log\;R}$. If you substitute $\epsilon$ with $R^{-1}$ in the definition of box dimension then, in the limit of $R\rightarrow\infty$ you obtain the same value, so that you can interchange the two estimates whenever $R$ is large enough, say so large that only a negligible set of your particles are distant less than $R^{-1}$.

This said, let's come to the plot.

On the rightmost part, is obvious that you are considering values of $R$ for which you are encircling almost all of your particles, so you should discard your data.

On the leftmost side, on the other hand, you have a sort of offset in your dimension which is most likely due to making your estimate on a local cluster of particles.
At this stage this part of the data is not to be considered either.

In order to understand which data to discard on the left side you should:

- check that the particles are almost all at distances larger than $R_{min}^{-1}$ from each others;
- average the estimate around your distribution of particles for the smaller values of the radius;

This last step will give you some error bars to put on the data and probably will also reduce the offset you are seeing on the left side of your graph. Be careful to implement this averaging without including (almost empty) balls on the edge of your distribution, because these would ruin your estimate.

---

Edit: looking at the numbers I realize that probably most of your data are not in the range that makes your quantity equivalent to the box dimension. However I would say that the quantity you are considering may have a dignity of its own as scaling dimension. I don't know how much this can be similar to other estimates of fractal dimension, like the box dimension or the Haussdorff dimension.

You could make a separate fit for the region in which $R$ is so large that (almost) all the particles are at distances larger than $R^{-1}$ and see the difference between the results.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. **I have made a mistake on my data and corrected it. In fact, The right column is the number of particle N(r) into radius r and the left column is the radius r**. But about your answer, I should be mention that the main answer for solving the problem is to find R min and R max. After that, we can fit over the plot in the scaling region (**R min < R < R max**).  Is there a way to find the region from the data? (size of particles equals to lattice constant (unit)  and size of the square lattice is 1024 * 1024)

Comment: yeah basically when $N_{tot} - N(R) < N(R) - N(R_{previous}) $ you approximately have reached $R_{max} $ (where the subscript previous indicates the R used for the before last estimate), while when $\sqrt{\pi R^2/N(R)}>1/R $ you are at sufficiently large values of $R$ (the left hand side is a very rough estimate of the distance between the particles). To have the correct estimate of you R min you should compute the distribution of the distance between nearest particles and use 1/R< dmin, where you take dmin to be a distance so small that say 95% of your particles have their nearest neighbour

Comment: * nearest neighbour at a larger distance than dmin. Sorry for the format but I can't do better right now

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. I want to find **R min** and **R max** on above data and based on your explanation, actually, I did not understand to find it. Would you mind helping me to find an exact number for **R min** and **R max** on above data?

Comment: sorry but I have no time to do that. Let me explain a bit more precisely two things:
basically the $R_{max}$ will be where the (approximatively) linear growth of $log\;N(R)$ stops, the formula I gave you is just a way to extract that computationally.
To find the $R_{min}$ you can first use the inequality with pi and square root, that is a good approximation if your distribution of particles does not have too many inhomogeneities. If it does you need to estimate the shortest distance of separation between the particles.

Comment: If there is a lower bound to this separation use this and impose $R^{-1}$ to be lower than this bound. This will give you $R_{min}$. If your particles can be at distance zero, then you cannot take zero but you have to look at the distribution of the distance from the nearest neighbor: for each particle you need to see how distant is the nearest particle. Maybe there will be a couple of particle that are almost in the same point, but the 99% or 95% of the particles will be at a distance from their nearest neighbor greater than a certain value $d_{min}$, so you can use $R_{min}^{-1}\leq d_{min}$

Comment: remember to average your estimate over the set for the small values of the radius, as I told you in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your all answers.